# Search not finding whole words?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I am using **Magento 1.9.3.2** and when I search for **mercedes** on my site, it finds several products such as **Original Mercedes-Benz Typenzeichen Zeichen Hecktür Flügeltür SPRINTER**.

Now, when I search for **mercedes-benz**, it finds nothing. How could that be? Its also part of the name. I did a reindex of the search index, but that did not help. My search is set to **like and fulltext**.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using standard magento mysql based search?

Comment: Yes I do, I tried all variations (LIKE and FULL, only LIKE,...), no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is case sensitive and there is a mercedes with a lower case in the product description of Original Mercedes-Benz Typenzeichen Zeichen Hecktür Flügeltür SPRINTER. Did you check the results with Mercedes-Benz ?

Comment: I tried, yes, "Mercedes-Benz" does not give any results, "Mercedes-Ben" returns the desired results ... isnt that strange?